# positioning in CSS without using the position element

Tags: css

I need to have all my IDs not move when zooming in and out of the page without using the relative, absolute, or fixed positioning. I got the outer, letters and numbers box to stay when I zoom in and out but not the IDs

```
.outer {
margin: auto;
border: 20px outset orange;
width: 80%;
overflow: auto;
}

.letters {
border: 10px solid red;
float: left;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.numbers {
border: 10px solid blue;
float: right;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
clear: auto
}


#one {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: palegoldenrod;
text-align: center;
}

#two {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: salmon;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 120px;
}

#three {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: greenyellow;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 240px;
}

#four {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: plum;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 120px;
}

#five {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: thistle;
text-align: center;
}

#oneA {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: palegoldenrod;
text-align: center;
float: right;
}

#twoA {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: salmon;
text-align: center;
float: right;
margin-top: 120px;
}

#threeA {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: greenyellow;
text-align: center;
float: right;
margin-top: 240px;
}

#fourA {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: plum;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 502px;
margin-right: 120px;
float: right;
}

#fiveA {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px dashed aqua;
background-color: thistle;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 622px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Your Question Not Clear

Comment: I cannot use any position element in the CSS and everything needs to stay in the correct spot as you use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out of the page

Comment: Zoom is not predictable across different browsers / platforms. I don't really see how you could do this without using the `position` attribute... I also don't see the problem with using `position:relative` in this case, as everything would still be aligned to the right per your `float:right` rule?

Comment: Its for an assignment and I cannot see any way of doing it without the position attribute. even with the 'float:right' rule they move around when I zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any elements that should move? If not i would recommend disabling zoom:

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```